# how to check if user input has same characters in char list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that my question is vague. I'm new to python and I am trying to write a program that basically calculates the compatibility between two people by checking if characters in their names are present in ' True Love '.

For example:

Zac Efron
Emma Watson

check if any letters in 'True Love' are present in names given by user. It then adds them up and gives a percentage. It will check first for 'TRUE' and give a number 'x' then same for 'LOVE' and give the other number 'y', numbers will then be put side by side to make a whole number xy%.

I know it is still not clear but I got nothing to lose.

Here's my code, I know its bad and flawed:

```
def fname(f):
   return [char for char in f]

def sname(s):
   return [char for char in s]


f = input("What is the first person's full name?: ").upper().replace(" ", "")
s = input("What is the second person's full name?: ").upper().replace(" ", "")

print("Hello, " + f + " and " + s + ".")

# Checking if whitespace is removed and made uppercase.

print(fname(f))
print(sname(s))

# listing the letters in True love

t = ["T", "R", "U", "E"]
l = ["L", "O", "V", "E"]
tl = t + l
print(tl)
```

I only came up with this much and I'm stuck here.

Any help would be appreciated, and if you have any questions about what I am trying to do, please ask away.

Comment: What, *specifically*, are you "stuck" on?  What are the flaws?

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting your code. As Scott Hunter pointed out, you need to be very specific. Breakdown the issue into smaller problems and questions. Then research on specific questions. You will be surprised that many have had similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

Set intersections might be a nice way to do this:

```
>>> true_love = set("True Love".lower())
>>> len(
...     (set(input("First name? ").lower()) 
...         | set(input("Second name? ").lower())
...     ) & true_love
... ) / len(true_love)
First name? Zac Efron
Second name? Emma Watson
0.625
```

The idea is that since you're looking for letters in common, you turn each string into a `set` of letters.  Sets have a built-in operator for finding the number of elements they have in common (the *intersection*, which is the `&` operator).  You build the set that contains the *union* (`|`) of the two names, you intersect that with "True Love", and then compare the sizes of those sets to get a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, could do some improvement, but for what you need:

First you count how many letters from the inputs are in `tl`.

```
count=0
for x in f+s:
  if x in tl:
   count+=1
```

Or

```
count=0
for x in fname(f)+fname(s):
  if x in tl:
   count+=1

print((count * 100)/len(tl),'%')
```

Then, using the simple rule of 3:
You have 100% for all letters in `tl`. ?% for count.

```
print((count * 100)/len(tl),'%')
```

Besides that, about your code:

instead of `fname` and `sname` funcs you can use `list(f)`, `list(s)`;
`tl` could be `list("TRUE LOVE")`

Comment: So I followed what you suggested and I did it for both t and l since I need to different numbers to make the %. its not really about multiplying by 100 it's just me putting both numbers together to make a new number. However, I don't know how to put both together.      count_1 = 0
count_2 = 0
for x in f + s:
    if x in t:
        count_1 += 1
    if x in l:
        count_2 += 1

print(count_1, count_2)

Comment: I figured it out!

Comment: Glad to hear that!